# xdebug failing to go into the laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, xdebug, sentry, raven

I'm a big fan of using xdebug with laravel (esp in [vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14161/14510)). However recently something weird has been happening (Note: my xdebug works perfectly when I'm running it on unit tests with this command:

> php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit

1. I first put a breakpoint in a controller method for example
2. I run the command on the browser that would trigger an http call that will call that controller method
   the breakpoint appears here: (project/path/serve.php)

<

```
<?php <------- breakpoint appears here

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

if i type the command "get all context" i get this:

```
$uri                 = /* uninitialized */'';
```

stepping through goes to the if ($uri line, in which case the uri is properly shown in the contxt

as i step through to past the end of that file, it immediately jumps here:

```
/**
 * Handle the PHP shutdown event.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handleShutdown()
{
    if (! is_null($error = error_get_last()) && $this->isFatal($error['type'])) {
```

at

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
```

then it immediately goes to the [raven](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-raven) service provider:

```
/**
 * Register the service provider.
 */
public function register()
{

    ..
    // Register the fatal error handler.
    register_shutdown_function(function () {
        if (isset($this->app['Raven_Client'])) { <---- comes here
            (new Raven_ErrorHandler($this->app['Raven_Client']))->registerShutdownFunction();
        }
    });
```

at

```
Jenssegers\Raven\RavenServiceProvider->Jenssegers\Raven\{closure}()
```

then here @ Raven_Client->onShutdown() /path/to/project/vendor/sentry/sentry/lib/Raven/Client.php:1388

```
public function onShutdown()
{
    if (!defined('RAVEN_CLIENT_END_REACHED')) { <--
        define('RAVEN_CLIENT_END_REACHED', true);
    }
    $this->sendUnsentErrors();
    if ($this->curl_method == 'async') {
        $this->_curl_handler->join();
    }
}
```

then here @ Raven_ErrorHandler->handleFatalError() /path/to/project/vendor/sentry/sentry/lib/Raven/ErrorHandler.php:126

```
public function handleFatalError()
{
    unset($this->reservedMemory); <---

    if (null === $error = error_get_last()) {
        return;
    }

    if ($this->shouldCaptureFatalError($error['type'])) {
        $e = new ErrorException(
            @$error['message'], 0, @$error['type'],
            @$error['file'], @$error['line']
        );
        $this->handleException($e, true);
    }
```

then here @ Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler->__destruct() /path/to/project/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractHandler.php:169

```
public function __destruct()
{
    try {
        $this->close();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // do nothing
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

how do i stop this from happening?

## update

i removed the raven service provider from my env by doing this:

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $env = config('app.env');

    if (!$env === 'local' || !$env === 'testing') {
        $this->app->register(\Jenssegers\Raven\RavenServiceProvider::class);
        $this->app->alias('Raven', Jenssegers\Raven\Facades\Raven::class);
    }
```

but then now when I debug, it still goes here:

```
/**
 * Handle the PHP shutdown event.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handleShutdown()
{
    if (! is_null($error = error_get_last()) && $this->isFatal($error['type'])) {
```

at

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
```

but it skips the raven stuff.. so this is really my problem. There is an error that's happening but i would like to debug *before* i reach that error..

## update 2

- I noticed that breakpoints in the middleware works just fine, but then it proceeds to skip my controller
- If I make the request from postman (I switched to the login api for smoketesing), it works just fine, this is what my postman command looks like (converted to curl):

>

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/login' \
  --header 'Accept: application/x.toters.v1+json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  --form 'email={{client_user_name}}' \
  --form 'password={{general_password}}'
```

in the other hand, this is the request from the browser that doens't work:

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/login'
-X OPTIONS 
-H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' 
-H 'Origin: http://localhost:3000' 
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' 
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' 
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36' 
-H 'Accept: */*' 
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
-H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type' --compressed
```

Comment: If the debugger jumps to any exception handler, is there any exception caught?

Comment: i don't think it's even making it to the part yet.. this whole thing happens before the exception part is reached at all

Comment: relevant: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/lifecycle

Comment: Are you running the webserver on the same system you use for development? I've had similar problems when using Apache on a debian system and developing locally on a Windows system where the `vendor` folder did not contain all packages

Comment: Both on the same env

Comment: I'm having a similar issue in the context of WordPress, where XDebug first stops on `WP_Fatal_Error_Handler`, but after enabling `WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER` it stops on various `__destruct()` in WordPress classes. I also am not sure how to get around this.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue recently, the problem is that xdebug is stopping at the first line of execution, the key to solving this problem is

```
let g:vdebug_options = {'break_on_open': 0}
```

and what I did to fix it was put into `.vimrc` the following settings for xdebug

```
  let g:vdebug_options = {'ide_key': 'vim-xdebug'}
  let g:vdebug_options = {'break_on_open': 0}
  let g:vdebug_options = {'server': '127.0.0.1'}
  let g:vdebug_options = {'port': '10000'}
  let g:vdebug_options["path_maps"] = {
  \ "/project": "<project-path>"
  \}
```

I also installed this chrome extension [Xdebug helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc/related?hl=en) and it works fine now.

if you want to consult, these are my xdebug settings

**xdebug.ini:**

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so

[debug]
; Remote settings
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=10000

; General
xdebug.auto_trace=off
xdebug.collect_includes=off
xdebug.collect_params=off
xdebug.collect_return=off
xdebug.default_enable=off
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.manual_url=http://www.php.net
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.show_mem_delta=0
xdebug.max_nesting_level=500
xdebug.idekey=vim-xdebug

; Trace options
xdebug.trace_format=0
xdebug.trace_output_dir=/tmp
xdebug.trace_options=0
xdebug.trace_output_name=crc32

; Profiling
xdebug.profiler_append=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name=crc32
```

**php.ini**

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question though, I don't think breaking on the first line is what's happening in @abbood's case.